# Resizing page on load with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    <script> function resize(){
    myWindow.resizeTo(600, 500);
    myWindow.focus();
    }
    </script>
</script>
<style>
canvas{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

</head>

<body onload="resize()">
```

Why is this not working? When I add an alert to the function it works, it is just the resizing, please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers place lots of restrictions on `resizeTo`; here's [Firefox's list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.resizeTo).

Fundamentally, if your code didn't open the window, or it's a tab not a window of its own, you can't resize it. You probably *can* resize it if you opened it with `window.open` providing the third argument (dimensions, features, etc.) and the browser created a new window (rather than tab).